# Android, cannot write to SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I've been banging on my head against the wall for a while now. I cannot understand why this isn't writing to the SD card, and if it is, then where is it?

The path says /storage/sdcard0 when i run
    System.out.println(sdcard.getAbsolutePath());

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "dirname");
    dir.mkdir();
    File file = new File(dir, "filename.txt");
    FileOutputStream outStream;
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        String data = "CONTENT";
        outStream.write(data.getBytes());
        outStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My manifest has the permission inside and i'm pretty sure it's in the correct place

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testing_pdf_processing"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Please!! any help would be much appreciated as I can't work this out at all.

Comment: I think you need a path separator after `getAbsolutePath` and before `"dirname"`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, do you mean like;   File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "dirname");
?  I've just tried that and it didn't work

Comment: Yes. How do you check for the file?

Comment: I'm looking around on the SD card / the tablet in windows explorer,  i've hidden files/folders off, thought i'd be able to see it?

Comment: ok I just tried with    File file2 = new File(sdcard,"/dirname/filename.txt");
       if(file2.exists()){
        System.out.println("hey");
        }  and it worked.. god i'm silly sometimes, thank you very much :)

Comment: That makes no sence to use a windows explorer. Install a file explorer app (like ES File Explorer) on your device and use that. Do realise that more often than not GetExternalStorageDirectory delivers a path to external memory which is not the removable sdcard.

Comment: thank you greenapps too, yes I didn't realise that. I thought i could see all memory from inside windows explorer for some reason